# jquery segment displays wrong number all the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a wheel of fortune type animation using jquery but for some reason the code that i am using always displays the wrong number!

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf49mqaa/2/

click on the WHITE AREA in the wheel to see the animation and you will see a wrong number will be shown!

at the moment I only have 4 columns and 4 segments in my jquery code but in the future i am will pull the amount of segments from a database and I  need this to work correctly at all times and display the correct number.

I tried everything from changing the `segment = Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 4)),`  to `segment = Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 4) -1),` and also `segment = Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 5)),`

and it still display wrong number!

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with wrong number? Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 4)) gives a number between 1-4. Selection from the array with this.cache.wheelMapping[(segment - 1)] returns corresponding value. For example segment 1 returns win 4 http://jsfiddle.net/wf49mqaa/4/

Comment: @axel.michel, the number that is returned in the alert is different than the number that is under marker and that is wrong. if number 4 is under the marker, then the number 4 should be in the alert, if number 2 is under the marker, then number 2 should be in the alert... but currently the number that is under the marker is different than the number that is displayed in the alert pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the Code you use I found in a [Non-working demo from sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-wheel-fortune-demo/)., digging a bit deeper there are two different errors/ problems to solve the fortune-wheel behavior:

**First: How to define the degree:**

```
// existing code fragment (wrong)
var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
```

This would cause the wheel to stop at a totally random position, but that is not what you need. The wheel should always stop at the marker position, it should just turn around by a random number of segments.

```
// supposing you have a wheel with 4 segments (here the items array):

var deg = 0, /* basic degree */
    spinbase = 1080, /* basic spinning of the wheel, here 3 times full turn */
    items = [1,2,3,4];

// your spinning function...
spin: function () {
    var min = 1, 
        max = 10, 
        rand = Math.floor(min + Math.random()*(max+1-min));
    [...]
        // like this you'll stop at the same position, 
        // but the wheel moved by a random number of segments
        deg = deg + ( Math.round( 360 / items.length ) * rand) + spinbase;
    [...]
}
```

**Second: How to get the correct segment:**

In short:

```
   // where deg is the current degree, and items the array from above.
   var segmentIndex = Math.ceil(
    (deg - (360 * parseInt(deg / 360))) / 
        Math.round(360/items.length)
   );
```

And when filling the algorithm..

```
   // e.g. deg is (degree of each segment) * random (here 5) + 1080
   // deg = 1530 (1080 + ( (360/4) * 5) )
   // (1530 - (360 * parseInt( 1530 / 360))) / Math.round(360 / 4);
   // (1530 - (360 * 4)) / 90;
   // 90 / 90 = 1
   // since we have 4 segments only and the random number is higher, 
   // the wheel did another full turn + 1 (from the starting number) 
   // so we get items[ 1 ] = (result: 2);
   // due to the ceil/floor/round methods in calculation it can happen
   // that you reach the extrem values segments.length or less than 0,
   // to fix this:

    var segmentIndex = Math.ceil(
    (deg - (360 * parseInt(deg / 360))) / 
        Math.round(360/items.length)
   );

   if(target < 0 ) { target = segment.length - 1; }
   if(target === segments.length ) { target = 0; }
   alert( 'Winning: ' + items[target] );
```

Putting this together you'll get a working [fortune-wheel](http://jsfiddle.net/d3838quo/7/). I allowed myself to create a new variant of the fortune wheel, which is able to handle different amounts of segments to make it easier to prove the algorithm.

Comment: you seem to change the image! when i change the image to the original one which had only 4 column [1,2,3,4], and I change the segments accordingly, still doesn't work and it throws out a wrong number!

Comment: I have updated your code with 1,2,3,4 and changed the image to have 4 segments and now it doesn't work! is there anything else that needs to change apart from the amount of segments?!  here is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/wf49mqaa/12/

Comment: @user3806613 correct, code is still buggy. I decided to create a new version of the fortune wheel, that allows to play around with the number of segments and their corresponding calculation. See updated answer - Fiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/d3838quo/6/

Comment: This is amazing! how easy/hard is it to change the code so it can handle more than 10 segments?

Comment: I know this is the bit that creates the circle: baseCirc = [600,600,600,600,550,520,520,495,492,485], but I don't understand the math behind it. could you please elaborate?

Comment: even if you comment your code I would appreciate greatly mate.

Comment: @user3806613 No math behind it - it's just used to handle the inaccurate creation of the segments by using css border property (looks equal but they are not). To create perfect (and mathematical correct) segments you'll should use canvas or svg where you can draw real shapes, using this you could calculate size by (2 * Math.pi * radius) / element.length, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3838quo/7/